# How can I match one 'id' from a database table to another - Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, one-to-one

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm having trouble matching an 'id' from one database table to another.

In my view, I am displaying a table with data being fetched from my database. One column of the table is an 'id' being pulled from the 'claims' table.

I also have an 'accounts' table that stores the 'account_name' for the relevant 'id'. So I am trying to display the 'account_name' where it matches the'id'.

**Code in Controller**

```
$account = Account::orderBy('account_name')->get();

$data = [
'claim_data' => $claim_data,
'client' => $client,
'start_date' => $start_date,
'end_date' => $end_date,
'capacity' => $capacity,
'status' => $status,
'account' => $account
];

$returnHTML = view('reports._get_client_claim_report')->with($data)->render();
```

**Code In View**

```
<td>{{ ($claim->client_account_id == $account->id ? $account->account_name : '') }}</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what problem are you running into?

Comment: Please add the structure of your two tables to your post in order to better understand and better help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use laravel relationships if you need to get data based on parent table.

As per your table design you need to choose relations.

So your code will be looks like this,

```
$account = Account::with('relationShipName')->orderBy('account_name')->get();
```

In `Account` Model

```
public function relationShipName() {
      return $this->hasOne('AnotherModel:class');
}
```

If you have designed your table structure as per laravel standards then it will work otherwise you need yo pass your `local` & `foreign` key.

For more:
[Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)